# A regex phone reformatting for JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have phone number like: 89227611508 and i need to reformat this with regex(JS) into +8 922 761-15-08. I'm new in regex and can't get it done. Can anyone provide a simple solution?

Comment: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/javascript

Comment: @n00dl3 I know i can use this: https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js, but i just need it in one place and one time. I think it will be better to use a regex to reformat phone.

Comment: You can use something like this: `"89227611508".replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "+$1 $2 $3-$4-$5")`

Comment: Regular expressions do not format. They match.

Comment: Just be aware that users may input phone numbers in a very different ways, they may add 0 between the country code and the rest of the number, they may surround it with something, most likely like this: (0). They may add + or 00 before the number, or they may skip the country code. So, I wouldn't use regular expressions. Enjoy :-) BTW, what country has +8?

Comment: @strah Russia. I just needed to reformat number that coming from PHP.

Comment: Russia is `7`, 8 is `trunk code` within Russia, therefore notation `+8...` is incorrect, just my two cents.

Comment: @strah Yes, you are right. But  `+8` is only for Russia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
"89227611508".replace(/^(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, "+$1 $2 $3-$4-$5");
```

Comment: Looks almost identical to @Titus comment about 5 minutes earlier, maybe you should have credited him ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regular expression to grab the groups of numbers then concatenate the number groups into a formatted string.

```js
let number = '89227611508';

console.log(formatNumber(number));

function formatNumber(number) {
  let groups = number.match(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
  return '+' + groups[1] + ' ' + groups[2] + ' ' + groups[3] + '-' + groups[4] + '-' + groups[5];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```